# malloc less than 8 bytes

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc

Does it make sense to malloc say 4 bytes on the heap given that malloc internally would often round this up to a 8 byte boundary on 32 bit systems and 16 for 64-byte systems for its internal use.

I need to allocate a string that stores a single or a double digit number. I thus need a maximum of 3 bytes (2 for the two digits and 1 for the '\0' character to terminate my string). Wondering if there is any benefit of doing a malloc 3 and if i should instead do a malloc of 8?

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `std::string` and stop worrying about allocating and freeing memory for strings.

Comment: Is memory really an issue here or you just trying to optimize?

Comment: Allocate whatever memory you need. If you need 3 bytes and you ask for 8, what would you do with the extra 5 bytes? And if you have a legitimate use for those 5 bytes, define a 8 byte structure and go with it.

Comment: Whether you allocate the extra bytes and don't use them or the heap allocator does makes of course *absolutely* no difference.  Other than to the hapless victim that has to maintain your code some day.

Comment: @iharob: Probably... because it is equally valid for either. Though that might be coincidence.

Comment: @Sorry its on C and not C++. However you could use malloc for both C and C++ and hence had selected C++ as well.

Answer (score 3):

Allocate what you need and don't worry about memory usage.

Smart memory allocators will have separate pools of memory for allocating small chunks.

For example, a memory allocator may have a separate pool of memory for allocating items smaller than 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it absolutely makes sense only to ask for what you need.

The allocator (`malloc`, `new`, `VirtualAlloc` or what have you) may always pad your allocations, but that's not your concern, in general.
Anyway, it may pad bigger allocations more than smaller ones, due to mixing schemes / different pools for different sizes.

Anyway, don't worry over that overhead unless you have lots of allocations, so the allocator-overhead might be the straw that breaks the camel's back.

In addition, the allocator may be changed or simply replaced (for better space/time-performance, debug-experience, fault-tolerance, just because), and you really don't want to leak all the details of how the last allocator worked all over your code.

Especially you don't want to go out of your way to counter any possible improvement resulting from better tuning to your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Best to request the needed size and not a larger amount as well answered by [*Deduplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949214/2410359)

There is an important exception should OP find a future need to allocate `0` bytes.

In that case, allocators like `malloc(0)` may return `NULL` or a pointer - either is allowed by the C spec.  This may confuse or break subsequent code that specifically expects one of those two.  So when code needs to allocate `0` bytes, consider returning `malloc(1)` or `NULL` and not leaving it up to `malloc(0)`.

Comment: That's an important gotcha. And imho a real wart on the language, especially when moving to `realloc`.

Comment: A need to allocate `0` bytes?  Can you explain why someone would do that intentionally?

Comment: @fiddlingBits, yes I have had cases where I wanted allocate a variable amount of space which under circumstances could be 0 and there you have to be careful: `malloc(nbytes)` returning `NULL` is not necessarily an error with `nbytes == 0` and here one could lead to the other in the following steps so you just decide always to allocate at least one byte -- pure pragmatism

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Just wondering why you'd go ahead with `malloc(0)` instead of checking for `0` first: `if(nbytes > 0) malloc(nbytes)`.  By the way: Deutschland über alles. :-D

Comment: @FiddlingBits -- just because the poiner bein NULL led to confusion afterwards.. Grüße aus Offenbach